# sql server agent не может запустится

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

не возможно запустить sql server agent

Answer (score 0):

1. Нужно всегда смотреть протокол сообщений и ошибок ОС - это общее замечание.
2. Скорее всего для SQL Server Agent не сконфигурировано никаких задач.